# Having trouble installing PyQt5 using conda on Mac OS

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, conda

I think its telling me it wants to use Python 3.7 but the message is confusing so I made 3.7 the default for the terminal shell, but I still get the following:

```
dzimmerman@QA-Bonjour-OSX ~ % python --version
Python 3.7.2
dzimmerman@QA-Bonjour-OSX ~ % conda install -c dsdale24 pyqt5
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pyqt5 -> python=2.7

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

Comment: I think it says pyqt5 is compiled for 2.7, not 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

The `pyqt5` package in the channel you are trying to use is compiled only for python 2.7.

You should use the version from `conda-forge` which also provides `pyqt5` and has versions for pyhton 3.7 on OsX:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyqt
```

Comment: thank you that installed successfully. I am still trying to resolve another issue (which is why I wanted to terminal install Pyqt) when I try to run a PyQt "Hello World" it gives me the following: dzimmerman@QA-Bonjour-OSX Desktop % python3 Build.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Build.py", line 10, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow  # QWidget
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5' .   I've tried adding paths to just about everywhere to no avail!